# How to let IDEA auto import pom.xml with Annotation Processors defined

Tags: java, intellij-idea, querydsl

I am using QueryDsl, so my source depends on generated code.

**FIRST**

Whenever IDEA (auto) imports pom.xml, the following setting is always empty:

> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Annotation Processors

I have to set it manually, which is very troublesome.

**SECOND**

I have multi-modules using QueryDsl, which I want to be grouped into one profile with the QueryDsl `com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor` applied.

> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> profile

I currently have to group these modules into one profile manually.

I also have to write a README and inform all members to follow the guide to set IDEA manually.

---

How can I config pom.xml, so that IDEA can fill these two settings automatically?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you add **.idea/*** under version control as well as the project **.iml** file.

> Annotation Processors

Annotation Processors settings are stored in **.idea/compiler.xml**. Having all this under CVS will make it a lot easier for other developers to open the project as they will open a ***project*** file, not a ***pom*** file, already containing project settings, run configurations, etc.

Details onto what should go in CVS and what not could be found on the official IntelliJ guide on [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

Comment: It should work, but is not a Maven friendly solution.

Comment: Is there a Maven plugin to control generations of `.idea/*` ?

Comment: For each time, the `pom.xml` is updated and re-auto-imported, the `.idea/compiler.xml` is also updated, so I am afraid the method will not work.

Comment: It seems gradle has an 'idea' plugin, it should/may ease this painpoint. I will update this post if I sucessed. If it did, I will move my build tool from Maven to Gradle.